# Python & RabbitMQ -- Communicate Between Parent & Children?

Tags: python, rabbitmq

I'd like to write a `python` script (call it **parent**) that does the following:

**(1)** defines a multi-dimensional `numpy` array

**(2)** `forks` 10 different `python` scripts (call them **children**). Each of them must be able to `read` the contents of the `numpy` array from **(1)** at any single point in time (as long as they are alive).

**(3)** each of the **child** scripts will do its own work (**children** DO NOT share any info with each other)

**(4)** at any point in time, the **parent** script must be able to accept messages from all of its **children**. These messages will be *parsed by the parent* and cause the `numpy` array from **(1)** to change.

---

How do I go about this, when working in `python` in a `Linux` environment? I thought of using `rabbitMQ` and have the **parent** be a producer (of the `numpy` array) to its children. On the other hand, each **child** must be able to transmit messages to the **parent**.

Which `rabbitMQ` model is most suitable for this?

Answer (score 0):

'Global Arrays' might be what you need.

Check it out, second talk: http://blip.tv/pycon-us-videos-2009-2010-2011/pycon-2011-friday-afternoon-lightning-talks-4902699

Comment: Uszy Wieloryba, thank you. What makes this better than a tool such as `rabbitMQ`?